# Problem with storing data into database using array

Tags: jquery, laravel

In controller parsing data, that is passed from jquery serialize and storing to database. question data is stored successfully but when i'm trying to save data of option a, option b, option c, option d, option e with same method so it is showing error.Please  help me in this

```
public function addQues(Request $request){
        $params = array();
         parse_str($_POST['data'], $params);

        $qs=$params['ques'];
        $opta=$params['opta'];
        $optb=$params['optb'];
        $optc=$params['optc'];
        $optd=$params['optd'];
        $opte=$params['opte'];
        $ans=$params['ans'];

        //print_r($opta);
            foreach ($qs as $x) {

               $ot=new onlinetest();
               $ot->question=$x;
               $ot->save();
            }

            foreach ($opta as $opt) {

                $ot=new onlinetest();
                $ot->opta=$opt;
                $ot->save();
             }
            }
```

Error:

> responseText: "{↵    "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'question' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `onlinetests` (`opta`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values

Even i have save the data of question in previous loop.

Comment: We can't correct your code, as you haven't shown the part which is making performing the SQL action. However, from the error we can tell you that the problem is because you're not giving a value for the `question` field, yet it's required and has no default value.

Comment: foreach ($qs as $x) {

               $ot=new onlinetest();
               $ot->question=$x;
               $ot->save();
            }
i'm saving the question through this loop  ....  next loop is for saving option a ....

Comment: Try changing  $_POST['data']  in line 3 to  $request

Comment: not working with $request too